# How can I change the shape of blocks in Scratch/Blockly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mit-scratch, google-blockly

I am trying to change the shape and color of the blocks in Scratch. To do so, I am trying to modify the GitHub repo of scratch-blocks (https://github.com/LLK/scratch-blocks).

There is a slight possibility that the repo I would have to change is the GitHub repo of scratch-gui (https://github.com/LLK/scratch-gui), even though I do not think so.

Has anyone done this before and could tell me which file/folder to rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Scratch addons https://scratchaddons.com/ You can customize block colors for scratch. Not sure about blockly, though